# How To Use arrayContains and not-in filters in a Firestore query?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

When I run arrayContains and whereNotIn together in a Firestore query like the code below:

```
firebaseFirestore.instance
             .collection('users')
             .where('onlineStatus', isEqualTo: true)
             .where('location', isEqualTo:  userFrom.location)
             .where('interest', arrayContains: callInterest)
             .where('userId', whereNotIn: ['a','b','x']).limit(1).get();
```

My app crashed with the following message

> An error occurred while parsing query arguments, this is most likely
> an error with this SDK......

Taking away the whereNotIn clause removes the error, so the error is most likely caused by using arraycontain and notIn together.

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations) on firestore merely states that not-in should not be used in the same query as array-contains-any. So I'd assume that not-in can work with array-contains but it seems to be otherwise.

Does anyone know if arrayContain can be used with notIn in a query together? Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like the error message is suggesting to you that there is an error in the SDK.  In that case, maybe you should file a bug report on GitHub.  https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire

Comment: There is a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/5661) on this and this has been raised to the Firebase Support Team. But there is no ETA for this as it is a feature request to get the Firebase documentation updated that “not-in and array-contains cannot be used together like not-in and array-contains-any ''. Meanwhile you can have a look at the workaround provided in this [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/129805446#comment6).The workaround provided is a little on the costlier side because of the splitting queries and higher number of reads.